# selenium.open("/"); generated an XHR 500: Internal Server Error

Tags: java, selenium

Any clues on what causes this?

Comment: Can you give more info - stack trace, excerpt from your test case? Did you call selenium.setUp(url, browser)? Did you start Selenium server? Does Selenium throw this error, or is it web server error Selenium gets when it tries to access URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks. Got the solution..For any other people who chance upon this problem, here is the solution:

Replace `setUp(...)` with

```
Integer port = 4444;
String browserString= "*firefox";
String url = "http://yoururl.com";
selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost",port,browserString,url) {
public void open(String url) { commandProcessor.doCommand("open", new String[] {url,"true"});};
selenium.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue in Selenium RC 1.0.3. Details can be found here: http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=408

The workaround for 1.0.3 is to overload the `open` command with one that passes a boolean as a second argument set to `true`.

Alternatively, you could wait for a new version to be released, however most development efforts are focused on Selenium 2. This is currently in alpha, and the latest version (2.0a4) does not have this issue.

Answer (score 1):

This one worked for me in Java.
If a URL(say testurl) brings up the XHR Response code 500 Internal server error, then dont use the selenium.open command to open the url. instead, try with `selenium.openWindow`. Something like this:

```
selenium.open("http://google.com"); //or any site that will open without an error
selenium.openWindow(testurl,"18");
selenium.selectWindow("18");
selenium.selectWindow("Google");  //or the window title of the site from step 1 above
selenium.close();
selenium.selectWindow("18");
```